# I need to pass a condition as an argument

Tags: java, selenium

Basically I need to pass a condition as an argument into a method, and keep verifying that condition until it changes its value.

Below I have an example of a method that presses a certain Keyboard key until a condition is met.

For instance, I have a case in which I'm trying to read the Terms of Service's Page and I need to press "Down" until the scroll bar reaches the bottom.

```
public static void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key, boolean condition) {
    while(condition) {
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Also, another way to solve my problem would be if I could pass a method into my pressKeyUntilCondition() so I could directly send my Boolean getHeightFromBottom() method into the While condition.

Comment: You should make a setter method which you will call each time you need to change the condition value. You can do your operation based on the condition in this setter method.

Comment: I wonder whether you're asking for some Selenium-included solution or just about how to write a nice Java code?

Comment: you should pass predicate as an argument

Comment: And how do I pass the arguments to the method, I have "pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, NavigationBar.getHeightFromBottom());" But "getHeightFromBottom()" is a boolean, not a Predicate

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Predicate for this. A Predicate is a boolean-valued function. 
This way you can test against your value until the condition is met.

```
 public static void pressKeyUntilCondition(List<String> key, Predicate<YourObjectType> condition) {
    while(condition.test(yourValueToCheck)) {
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to I pass the arguments to the method,
I have
"pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, NavigationBar.getHeightFromBottom());"

But "getHeightFromBottom()" is a boolean, not a Predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a predicate to you your method :

```
public static void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key, Predicate<Integer> condition) {
   while(condition.test(timesPressed)) {
      press(key);
      timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

And the condition that you pass could be for example :

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = integer -> integer == 3;
```

And if you need more "conditions to be evaluated you can create some model class that contains those two fields and create a predicate from it :

```
public class ConditionValues {
        private int timesPressed;
        private Keys key;
        //getters setters
}

Predicate<ConditionValues> predicate = values -> values.getMaxTimePressed() ==  3 && values.getKey() == Keys.DOWN;

public static void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key, Predicate<ConditionValues> condition) {
    ConditionValues conditionValues = new ConditionValues(Keys.DOWN, 0);
    while(condition.test(conditionValues)) {
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
        conditionValues.setTimesPressed(timesPressed);
    }
```

Ofcourse it is just a POC so you can make any adjustments as you wish for example passing desired key as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the exact thing that is asked, but from what I understand you can do the following.

If you want to check the dynamic solution, you may just check the method instead of a static `boolean` condition. Something like this:

```
private static final int BOTTOM_SCROLLBAR_POSITION = 777; // todo: change to your required position

private int getScrollBarPosition() {
    return 666; // todo: implement your scrollbar position logic
}

public void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key) {
    while (getScrollBarPosition() <= BOTTOM_SCROLLBAR_POSITION) { // using just an existing function
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

If you want to pass a configurable condition, you can use some class from `java.util.function`, like some `Predicate` or `BooleanSupplier`, for example:

```
private void callPressKeyUntilCondition() {
    pressKeyUntilCondition(
        Keys.ARROW_DOWN, 
        () -> getScrollBarPosition() <= BOTTOM_SCROLLBAR_POSITION // BooleanSupplier lambda implementation
    );
}

public void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key, BooleanSupplier conditionSupplier) {
    while ( !conditionSupplier.getAsBoolean() ) { // using just an existing function
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The pressKeyUntilCondition method should always receive a "Dynamic" condition as an argument, otherwise that method wouldn't be useful in other situations.

Comment: Of course. As you see, both of my options depend on dynamic logic in `getScrollBarPosition()` (sorry if isn't clear that returning constant there has to be replaced with real scroll bar logic).

Answer (score -1):

You probably want your condition to be changeable (not final).
So consider some interface with contains the real value (or check you need to do) that you can call.

Something like this:

```
public static void pressKeyUntilCondition(Keys key, Reference<Boolean> reference) {
    while(reference.get()) {
        press(key);
        timesPressed++;
    }
}
```

Another point to watch out for is that you do not consume endless cpu while looping, so you might want to check the value only occasionly or you might want to put your thread to sleep and only wake it up if the condition is fullfilled.

(So that only works if your key pressing action does not need to be applied constantly)